# Creating a select (dropdown) input with a dynamic list of options in a gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

The [Google App Script SelectionInput docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input) show selection inputs with a static list of options. Trying to create a dynamic options list like below:

```
var items = [...];

var selectWidget = CardService.newSelectionInput()
  .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
  .setTitle("Select an item")
  .setFieldName("item");

items.forEach(function (item) {
  selectWidget.addItem(item, item, false);
});
```

results in a runtime error:

```
Object does not have property 
    - /​Card/​sections[0]/​widgets[1]/​selection_control/​items. [line: 115, function: XYZ, file: Code]
```

How should I go about creating a selection input with dynamic options in my gmail addon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Addon Dropdown

I haven't built any addons in a while but I knew that I wanted to sometime in the future so I did a couple of examples for myself.  This is part of one of them.

```
function buildMessageCard(dfltObj){
  var card=CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('DropDown Tester'));
  var section=CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Making Choices');
  var makeAChoice=CardService.newSelectionInput().setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
  .setTitle('Make a Choice')
  .setFieldName('userChoice')
  .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('saveChoice'))
  for(var i=1;i<dfltObj.selections;i++){
    makeAChoice.addItem('Choice ' + i, i, (i==dfltObj.finalChoice)?true:false);
  }
  section.addWidget(makeAChoice);
  var choiceText=CardService.newTextInput()
  .setTitle('Final Choice')
  .setFieldName('finalChoice')
  .setValue(dfltObj.finalChoice);
  section.addWidget(choiceText);
  card.addSection(section);
  return card.build();
}

function saveChoice(e){
  var cObj={finalChoice:e.formInput.userChoice};
  setDefaults(cObj);
  return buildMessageCard(getDefaults());
}

var Default_URL='dflturl';

function setDefaults(dfltObj){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(Default_URL);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Defaults');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(typeof(dfltObj[vA[i][0]])!='undefined'){
      vA[i][1]=dfltObj[vA[i][0]];
    } 
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}

function getDefaults(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(Default_URL);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Defaults');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dfltObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    dfltObj[vA[i][0]]=vA[i][1];
  }
  return dfltObj;
}
```

So you could change the number of selections dynamically with a little code and with a little more thought you could probably figure out how to change the options.

Here is the hash table for my dfltObj:

[image]

- [SelectInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input)

Comment: Apparently, you will have to rebuild that unique card to get it to read the new default values.  But it looks like it does that between emails and if what your doing is actually a part of the addon then you could have it rebuild the card after changing the defaults. I should point out that the only items that apply to this example are finalChoice and selections.  The rest are for other parts of the project that I didn't share.